# Где в python requests аналог curl --proxy-insecure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, proxy, heroku

Как в python с помощью requests сделать https-запрос через прокси с отключением проверки сертификатов (аналог ключа `--proxy-insecure` в curl)? Мой код:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://ip.quotaguard.com', proxies={'https': 'login:password@eu-west-shield-01.quotaguard.com:9294'}, verify=False)
```

`verify=False` тоже используется, но это не относится к вопросу, т.к. это аналог ключа `-k` в curl, он отключает верификацию на ip.quotaguard.com, а на прокси `eu-west-shield-01.quotaguard.com:9294` не отключает.

Код выдает ошибку `ValueError: check_hostname needs a SSL context with either CERT_OPTIONAL or CERT_REQUIRED`.

Через curl запрос успешно выдает результат, вот сам запрос:

```
curl -x "https://login:password@eu-west-shield-01.quotaguard.com:9294" -L "https://ip.quotaguard.com" --proxy-insecure -k
```

Если есть такая возможность, но не в requests, порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, другую библиотеку.